# java.lang.NullPointerException Spring Mvc

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException:

I have the getters and setters set for the validateUserNameManager.
I am using xml based configurations and not using @Autowire.
Its clear when processing reaches validateUserNameManager it gets the NP Exception i am not sure if my configurations and wiring are accurate.

```
if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName()) == true){

                    errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.exist");
                }
```

**OfficerRegistrationValidation.java**

```
public class OfficerRegistrationValidation implements Validator{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());


    private ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager;


    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return Officers.class.equals(clazz);
    }


    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        Officers officer = (Officers) target;

        if (officer.getUserName() == null){

            errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.required");

        }else{

            String userName = officer.getUserName();                    

            logger.info("OfficerRegistrationValidation - UserName is not null so going to check if its valid for :" + userName);

            try {

                logger.info("OfficerRegistrationValidation - Just before try.....catch block...userName is :" + userName);  

                logger.info("OfficerRegistrationValidation - about to evaluate if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName()) == true)" );


                if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName()) == true){

                    errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.exist");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                logger.info("OfficerRegistrationValidation - Error Occured When validating UserName");
                logger.error("Message", e);
                errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.error");
            }

        }

/**
     * @return the validateUserNameManager
     */
    public ValidateUserNameManager getValidateUserNameManager() {
        logger.info("Getting - ValidateUserNameManager");
        return validateUserNameManager;
    }


    /**
     * @param validateUserNameManager the validateUserNameManager to set
     */
    public void setValidateUserNameManager(
            ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager) {

        logger.info("Setting - ValidateUserNameManager");
        this.validateUserNameManager = validateUserNameManager;
    }       

}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="officerRegistrationValidation" class="com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation">

        <property name="validateUserNameManager" ref="validateUserNameManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="validateUserNameManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager">
        <property name="officerDao" ref="officerDao"/>
</bean>


<bean id="officerDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Servlet.xml

```
   <bean name="/officer_registration.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController">
        <property name="divisionManager" ref="divisionManager" />
        <property name="positionManager" ref="positionManager" />
        <property name="genderManager" ref="genderManager"/>  
    </bean>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean name="/validateUserName.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController">

        <property name="validateUserNameManager" ref="validateUserNameManager"/>    

    </bean>    


<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->
```

**StackTrace:**

```
47840 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate  - Converting String to [class java.lang.String] using property editor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor@7079b2]
47840 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - OfficerRegistrationValidation - UserName is not null so going to check if its valid for :adminzz
47840 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - OfficerRegistrationValidation - Just before try.....catch block...userName is :adminzz
47840 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - OfficerRegistrationValidation - about to evaluate if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName()) == true)
47840 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - OfficerRegistrationValidation - Error Occured When validating UserName
47840 [http-8084-1] ERROR com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation  - Message
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation.validate(OfficerRegistrationValidation.java:51)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:815)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @PaulTomblin if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName()) == true){

Comment: This function works since i use it in a web service call

Comment: How do you retrieve the OfficerRegistrationValidation-object?

Comment: Whee do you setValidateUserNameManager?

Comment: I am not doing a setValidateUserNameManager i thought this would happen when the function is called and the container would set it via the xml files. If i am wrong please advise me where i would have to do the setValidateUserNameManager

Comment: @Tobb This object is called in the Controller InitBinder method by using binder.setValidator(new OfficerRegistrationValidation()). The validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(officer.getUserName() is a complex validation i am doing in the validation class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you instantiate the OfficerRegistrationValidaton through a new call. This means that Spring won't know anything about the object, and thus will not wire anything into it.

You need to load the object through a Spring mechanism, either through @Autowire / @Inject, or through creating a BeanFactory, like this:

```
public final class BeanFactory() {

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getContext() {
        if (context== null) {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        }
        return context;
    }

    public static OfficerRegistrationValidation getOfficerRegistrationValidation() {
        return (OfficerRegistrationValidation) getContext().getBean("officerRegistrationValidation");
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller:

```
    BeanFactory.getOfficerRegistrationValidation().validate(....)
```

Note: Be careful with newing the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, this could lead to memory leaks if not done properly. Create a static factory that will new it once, and returned the same instance any following call.

Comment: This should be done where in the applicationcontext.xml file? I am still unclear can you elaborate please

Comment: Not in your applicationcontext, in the java class. The method loads the applicationContext(s) specified in the constructor, and makes available the beans. But you really should use autowiring, it makes things a lot easier..

Comment: I have never used Autowire can you tell me where i will have to place the Autowire annotation is it on the class and any instance of it?

Comment: You place it on the instance variable, so in the controller @Autowire OfficerRegistrationValidation officerRegistrationValidation. Also, you need to add something to the applicationContext to enable autowiring i think, but don't remember exactly what. I'm sure google will tell you..

Comment: What is config in the BeanFactory, is it an object?

Comment: @Todd i used Autowired and included  <context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="............. but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Ok i used the FactoryBean above and this worked like a charm.....config should be context you should make that change just to reflect accuracy and return (OfficerRegistrationValidation) getConfig().getBean("officerRegistrationValidation") should be return (OfficerRegistrationValidation) getContext().getBean("officerRegistrationValidation")